# MongoDB DSL filters

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, dsl

When filtering with DSL if the filters that are being passed are empty then the results are empty. Could you please give some suggestions on how to ignore URL parameters that are not set.

Example:

```
@Query(value ="{$and:[{'country.name':{$eq:?0}},{'providerName':{$eq:?1}}]})"
```

The above query is working fine and the documents are returned. But if the positional filters are null then the result is empty. How to write a query that ignores the parameters if the value is not set.

Kind Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would highly recommend to use Query API to build the query based on the parameter is being passed, but if you want to use query DSL, it can be done something like this, you have to check for null and can build the query accordingly.

```
@Query("{$and :["
        + "?#{ [0] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'country.name' : {$eq:[0]}} },"
        + "?#{ [1] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'providerName' : {$eq:[1]}}}"
        + "]}")
```

Reference: [mongodb.repositories.queries.json-spel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-spel)

Comment: The syntax is correct. But the returned documents are empty. It looks like the conditional operator checks for null values and assigns empty value nack to the variables.         Example:  If the variable [0]==null then it becomes country.name ={}

Comment: ohh ok, I think there is a small correction can you try this one? @Query(value ="{$and:[?#[0] == null ? {} : {'country.name':{$eq:?0}},?#[1] == null ? {}: {'providerName':{$eq:?1}}]})", If It works I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi there, we are thinking on the same lines. But did not work for me. The exception "JSON reader was expecting a value but found ':'.""                                                                                                                              Double checked if there is something wrong in query format. But in the first instant, it looks fine. I purposefully gave second input as normal like below                                              @Query(value ="{$and:[?#[0] == null ? {} : {'country.name':{$eq:?0}},{'providerName':{$eq:?1}}]}

Comment: @AjayKumarVasireddy I have added the updated query, this should work fine. Please check and let me know.

Comment: No @Deepak unfortunately, it did not work. And I am tending to give up on this and will try with API. The exception when using the query is "message": "JSON reader was expecting a value but found '}'.",

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is error prone and that's why I suggested to use Query API's for this case, but the query in the answer is working fine for me, I have tested and validated that, Not sure why it didn't worked for you. Good you gave up on this :)